# MiKTeX 2.9 64bit error with BulletsADF

Tags: miktex

I have this error

```
Process started: pdflatex.exe -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "TESI".tex

This is makeindex, version 2.15 [MiKTeX 2.9 64-bit] (kpathsea + Thai support). Scanning  input file TESI.idx....done (51 entries accepted, 0 rejected). Sorting entries....done (330 comparisons). Generating output file TESI.ind....done (100 lines written, 0 warnings). Output written in TESI.ind. Transcript written in TESI.ilg.

Trying to make PK font BulletsADF at 420 DPI...

Running miktex-makemf.exe...

miktex-makemf: The BulletsADF source file could not be found. Running ttf2pk.exe...

miktex-makepk: PK font BulletsADF could not be created.

Process exited with error(s)
```

but I'm able to compile the same .tex file with MacTeX on my mac. How can I deal with this?

Comment: Looks as if miktex forgets to activate the map files of the package. You can add them to your document with `\pdfmapfile{=BulletsADF.map}`. And make a bug report so that miktex corrects the problem.

Comment: Thank you, it works! How can I leave a bug report to miktek? I'm using TeXstudio as a free interface.

Comment: `http://sourceforge.net/p/miktex/bugs/?source=navbar`. You need to say that the adfsymbols package doesn't activate the map-files. A small minimal test file would be useful too.